# Is it possible to make and run changes in javascript files using chrome developer tools or firebug without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working an issue and problem is code is huge and deployed on some remote location and takes a lot of time to go through this process. Now, I know that in chrome developer tools we can open javascript files and modify/save them but problem is, changes are not reflected in application. for example, hello.js has something like this,

```
   sayHello : function() {

 // some existing code here.

 }
```

now, developer tools allows to modify this file to look like,

```
 sayHello : function() {

 // some existing code here.
 // additional code added at runtime.

 }
```

but problem I am facing is, this additional code is not reflected when I execute

> sayHello()

function again.

*Note: I am not trying to load any new script here.*

Comment: Can you link to a URL where I can reproduce this? DevTools does allow you to edit scripts on the fly, but you might be encountering an edge case that's making it not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without some more input on your action, but could be that you are changing the source code (in the browser cache) and you expect the object already in memory to change as well? In case put a break point before the object is instantiated and change the code at that moment and see what happens.

Comment: Thats not possible as, this file is just a collection of functions. break point in function wont be called unless some event/user input happens.

Comment: look at the example from google: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/
step 6 works for me